# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty dx /{(x^2-a^2)^2+b^4} $ returns a negative number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to evaluate $\int_0^\infty dx /((x^2-a^2)^2+b^4)$. And I seem to have an error that I cannot detect. Using

```
 Simplify[Integrate[1/((x^2 - a^2)^2 + b^4), {x, 0, Infinity}], a > 0 && b > 0]
```

I get

```
 ConditionalExpression[-((I \[Pi])/(2 Sqrt[a^4 + b^4] (Sqrt[a^2 - I b^2] + Sqrt[a^2 + I b^2]))), Im[Sqrt[a^2 + I b^2]] > 0 && Im[Sqrt[a^2 - I b^2]] > 0]
```

I assume this to mean: Take the roots with positive imaginary parts of  $\sqrt{a^2+ib^2}$ and $\sqrt{a^2-ib^2}$.   In other words, the value of
$$ -i\pi \over {2\sqrt{a^4+b^4} (\sqrt{a^2+ib^2} +\sqrt{a^2-ib^2})} $$
with a positive pure imaginary in the denominator.

But this implies the integral becomes negative, which it is not.
Where is my error?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a simpler form

```
f[a_, b_] =Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, Integrate[
    1/((x^2 - a^2)^2 + b^4), {x, 0, Infinity}] //
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
  Simplify]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[f[a, b], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -6, 6},
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The problem appears to be that Mathematica assumes certain values for `a` and `b` so that it can use a particular expression to obtain the result.  This is not (necessarily) consistent with the assumptions that you supply for `Simplify`.

The solution is to supply the assumptions around the integral, so that they can be accounted for there.  I believe that the following gives a credible result:

```
Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, FullSimplify[Integrate[1/((x^2 - a^2)^2 + b^4), {x, 0, Infinity}]]] // InputForm
```

returning

```
((-I/4)*(1/Sqrt[-a^2 - I*b^2] - 1/Sqrt[-a^2 + I*b^2])*Pi)/b^2
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
Integrate[1/((x^2 - a^2)^2 + b^4), {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```